# Unity3D: rendered texture has lower resolution than original image file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resolution, 360-panorama

I try to render cubic panorama. I have the scene with cube around main camera. Cube is constructed with 6 cubic faces. I read texture from the file that is not in application assets or resources folders, but in the file system of my PC. I put appropriate fragments of loaded texture on the cube faces with appropriate mainTextureScales and mainTextureOffsets.

Everything seems fine. But rendered panorama has terrible large pixels. It seems that the texture I have loaded was resized to much smaller size.

Sure, I have very large file that consists of 6 images 2048x2048. So, the whole image has 12288x2048 size. But the Texture2D I have loaded this file into has correct, not reduced size: 12288x2048.

When I load textures for cube faces not from single file but from 6 separate files (each file contains 2048x2048 texture for appropriate face) the resolution is much better.

Could you please help me find the way to keep all faces textures in single file and put this texture with original, not reduced resolution.

Comment: Can You share with us image of imporing settings of that textures?

Comment: @Woltus, I load texture not from application assets or resources, but from the device file system, in run-time. I can set texture importing parameters for inner application images (from Assets or Resources inner folders). Is it possible to specify texture import parameters for runtime loading via Www class?

Comment: If you're using a single file for all six faces of the cubemap, Unity's going to compress it because it can't handle a texture in memory being larger than 2048x2048.  Cubemaps, when imported into the editor as an asset, are split up and stored as six individual textures. Thus when you import via code, you run into the same limitation and workaround.

Comment: @Draco18s, is it possible to read the whole image 12288x2048 not as the texture but as pixels array without loosing the actual resolution? If so, I can split it to 6 separate textures.

Comment: I don't know. I haven't messed with reading large textures from disk before. And I've not touched cubemaps pretty much at all, only that the ones I *have* messed with I know are handled internally by the engine as six standard images (because I've been able to view them).